# Multiple Tasks in parallel - One Section "one after another"

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task

I have several tasks running the same method in parallel. For a specific part of this method. I want the tasks to go one after another (not parallel).

Background: In the specific Part, I open another Form, where the User enters a Password. I Don't want the User to enter the password for every single tasks. The first one should get saved in a global string and used by the other tasks.

```
private void S7_GetCPU()
{
    //Some Stuff

    if (CPUPassword != null)
    {
        EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
        this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
    }
    if (!this.CPU.PasswordValid)
    {
        CPUPassword = ((MainForm)mainform)
            .ShowInputMessage("Enter Password for CPU"), true);
        EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
        this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
    }

    //More Parallel-Stuff
}
```

I tried to put this part into a Invoke. The Input-Message opens only one time. But all other tasks freeze at that point, even after the first task has left the .invoke

```
private void S7_GetCPU()
{
    //Some Stuff
    this.Invoke(new System.Action(() =>
    {
        if (CPUPassword != null)
        {
            EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
            this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
        }
        if (!this.CPU.PasswordValid)
        {
            CPUPassword = ((MainForm)mainform)
                .ShowInputMessage("Enter Password for CPU"), true);
            EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
            this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
        }
    }));
    //More Parallel-Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by: [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock)

```
private static readonly object PWLock = new object();

private void S7_GetCPU()
{
    //Some Stuff
    lock(PWLock)
    {
        if (CPUPassword != null)
        {
            EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
            this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
        }
        if (!this.CPU.PasswordValid)
        {
            CPUPassword = ((MainForm)mainform)
                .ShowInputMessage("Enter Password for CPU"), true);
            EncryptedString pwd = new EncryptedString(CPUPassword);
            this.CPU.SetPassword(pwd);
        }
    }));
    //More Parallel-Stuff
}
```